# NSTextView setFormatter?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextfield, nstextview, nsformatter

With a `NSTextField` we can easially call `setFormatter` if we want to say for instance create a custom formatter that only allows numbers (take [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827014/how-to-limit-nstextfield-text-length-and-keep-it-always-upper-case) question for example).

But what if we want to apply a formatter to a `NSTextView`? There does not seem to be a way to set a formatter, unless I am overlooking something.

Any suggestions on how to get around this?

Comment: Have a look into this,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919786/how-do-i-set-a-custom-nsformatter-to-a-nstextview

Comment: I'm missing something in this question or you have a typo. In the first paragraph you say "we can easily call", in the second you say "there doesn't not seem to be a way"... What is the problem?

Comment: @JamesWebster my bad. Its `NSTextField` which `setFormatter` can be called on. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `NSFormatter` is designed for the format of a single line string. This intention matches against `NSTextField` which would usually show a single line (particularly if using a formatter).

The point of a formatter is both to format existing text for display and to validate text entry from a user. You can use a formatter with an `NSTextView` to perform both of these actions, you just need to do a little work yourself to process text before you add it to the view (`stringForObjectValue:`) or when a user enters it (`textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementString:` and `isPartialStringValid:newEditingString:errorDescription:`).